# How to show the FCM on the react native app while it is on foreground

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I want to show the notification when app is in foreground and it receives the FCM just WhatsApp and other application shows. On the background I am receiving the notification on the notification bar but nothing happen when it receives while user is using the app. I am looking something like default android small popup from top. I am using the following body to send the FCM.

```
    { 
 "to": "/topics/chatProperty_P00025_14", 
 "notification" : {
 "body" : "great match!",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
   "sound":"default",
   "vibrate":true
 },
 "data" : {
 "body" : "14_P00025",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
 "type" : "propertyChat",
   "sound":"default",
   "vibrate":true
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following sample code:

```
let message = {
        to: "fcm_device_token",
        data: {
            custom_notification: {
                body: "Your message",
                custom_data: "Any custom data you want to send",
                sound: 'default',
                priority: "high",
                show_in_foreground: true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which backend you are using?

Comment: I am sending these notification from Advance REST client

Comment: I saw in another thread that 'show_in_foreground' only works for iOS but not for android

Comment: Please take look at this: https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm#i-want-to-show-notification-when-app-is-in-foreground . I have tested and works fine. I have used node as backend.